# Set Xamarin Project Build Version in Visual Studio for Mac 17.0

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

Looks like Microsoft has changed a few things in Visual Studio for Mac 17.0. I can't find where I can set the build number for my project. I only see project version but the build number field seems gone -- see below.

The problem is that when I archive the project to submit to AppStoreConnect, it shows as version 1.0 and clashes with previous v1.0 I'd already submitted.

[image]

Comment: Don't have Mac handy, but maybe open info.plist?

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly where it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project's build number can be found in `info.plist`.